# Find the value of $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log (1 + a_n)}{\sin (a_n + \frac{\pi}{2})}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let $\{a_n\}$ be sequence of real numbers s.t $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} {a_n}^\frac{1}{n} =\frac{1}{4}$

Evaluate
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log (1 + a_n)}{\sin (a_n + \frac{\pi}{2})}$$

Comment: Perhaps, first, find $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_n$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $\lim a_n^{1/n} = 1/4 < 1$, by the root test, the series $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty a_n$ converges. Hence, $\lim a_n = 0$, which implies $\lim \log(1 + a_n)/\sin(a_n + \pi/2) = \log(1)/\sin(\pi/2) = 0$.

Comment: Plz attend another problem at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1100187/find-lim-n-to-infty-e-fraca-nn-sqrtn-sin-frac-sqrt2-sqr

Answer (score 3):

If $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n}=\frac{1}{4}$, for any $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a $N_\varepsilon\in\mathbb{N}$ such that:
$$\forall n\geq N_\varepsilon,\qquad a_n \in \left[\left(\frac{1}{4}-\varepsilon\right)^n,\left(\frac{1}{4}+\varepsilon\right)^n\right].$$
This implies $\lim_{n\to +\infty} a_n = 0,$ so $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\log(1+a_n)=0$ and $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\sin\left(a_n+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=1.$

Answer (score 3):

We have  from the hypothesis:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$$
and since in this case we have

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\log(1+a_n)=0$$
then the desired limit is simply $0$ (there isn't an indeterminate form.)

Comment: Great sir excellent